# Android error Xamarin Forms, "Resource ID #0x0", I think it is in my drawable but I have cleaned everything but still get error

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get an error when I try to run my app on Android. It gives me this:

"A Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException was thrown, Resource ID #0x0"

I reckon it has to do with my drawable when I put an image in there, but I tried to restore everything so I just have the defaulticon in my drawablefiles and then add em to update it but the error is still there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6gyX.jpg // the errors
Any idea?

Comment: Not without the code that's throwing the error...

Comment: updated. having trouble copy pasting that code so i put a imgur. http://imgur.com/E7SS9OC

Comment: That's a stack trace, which was going to be the next thing I was going to ask for.  Still need to see the code throwing the error.

Comment: ahh ok i thought that showed the error. how do I find the error? do I click "base", "static members" or "non-public members?" never done this before so bare with me!! hehe